# Apache/Tomcat error - wrong pages being delivered

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp

This error has been driving me nuts. We have a server running Apache and Tomcat, serving multiple different sites. Normally the server runs fine, but sometimes an error happens where people  are served the wrong page - **the page that *somebody else* requested!**

Clues:

- The pages being delivered are those that another user requested recently, and are otherwise delivered correctly. It's been known for two simultaneous requests to be swapped. As far as I can tell, none of the pages being incorrectly delivered are older than a few minutes.
- It only affects the files that are being served by Tomcat. Static files like images are unaffected.
- It doesn't happen all the time. When it does happen, it happens for everybody.
- It seems to happen at times of peak demand. However, the demand is not yet very high - it's certainly well within the bounds of what Apache can cope with.
- Restarting Tomcat fixed it, but only for a few minutes. Restarting Apache fixed it, but only for a few minutes.
- The server is running Apache 2 and Tomcat 6, using a Java 6 VM on Gentoo. The connection is with AJP13, and `JkMount` directives within `<VirtualHost>` blocks are correct.
- There's nothing of use in any of the log files.

---

**Further information:**

Apache does not have any form of caching turned on. All the caching-related entries in httpd.conf and related imports say, for example:

```
<IfDefine CACHE>
  LoadModule cache_module modules/mod_cache.so
</IfDefine>
```

While the options for Apache don't include that flag:

```
APACHE2_OPTS="-D DEFAULT_VHOST -D INFO -D LANGUAGE -D SSL -D SSL_DEFAULT_VHOST -D PHP5 -D JK"
```

Tomcat likewise has no caching options switched on, that I can find.

[toolkit's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246540/apachetomcat-error-wrong-pages-being-delivered#246566) was good, but not appropriate in this case. What leads me to believe that the error can't be within my own code is that it isn't simply a few values that are being transferred - it's the entire request, including the URL, parameters, session cookies, the whole thing. People are getting pages back saying "You are logged in as John", when they clearly aren't.

---

**Update:**

Based on suggestions from several people, I'm going to add the following HTTP headers to Tomcat-served pages to disable all forms of caching:

```
Cache-Control: no-store
Vary: *
```

Hopefully these headers will be respected not just by Apache, but also by any other caches or proxies that may be in the way. Unfortunately I have no way of deliberately reproducing this error, so I'm just going to have to wait and see if it turns up again.

I notice that the following headers are being included - could they be related in any way?

```
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=66
```

---

**Update:**

Apparently this happened again while I was asleep, but has stopped happening now I'm awake to see it. Again, there's nothing useful in the logs that I can see, so I have no clues to what was actually happening or how to prevent it.

Is there any extra information I can put in Apache or Tomcat's logs to make this easier to diagnose?

---

**Update:**

Since this has happened again a couple of times, we've changed how Apache connects to Tomcat to see if it affects things. We were using `mod_jk` with a directive like this:

```
JkMount /portal ajp13
```

We've switched now to using `mod_proxy_ajp`, like so:

```
ProxyPass /portal ajp://localhost:8009/portal
```

We'll see if it makes any difference. This error was always annoyingly unpredictable, so we can never definitively say if it's worked or not.

---

**Update:**

We just got the error briefly on a site that was left using `mod_jk`, while a sister site on the same server using `mod_proxy_ajp` didn't show the error. This doesn't prove anything, but it does provide evidence that swithing to `mod_proxy_ajp` may have helped.

---

**Update:**

We just got the error again last night on a site using `mod_proxy_ajp`, so clearly that hasn't solved it - `mod_jk` wasn't the source of the problem. I'm going to try the anonymous suggestion of turning off persistent connections:

```
KeepAlive Off
```

If that fails as well, I'm going to be desperate enough to start investigating GlassFish.

---

**Update:**

Dammit! The problem just came back. I hadn't seen it in a while, so I was starting to think we'd finally sorted it. I hate heisenbugs.

Comment: To completely eliminate the possibility of caching, you can insert a servlet filter in front of all requests, that sets appropriate response headers according to

http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/

Comment: That's not a bad idea. I may also add explicit directives to Apache to prevent caching of any of the relevant addresses. It may fix nothing, but the worst it can do is help eliminate options.

Comment: I would lean toward something your app is doing.  The logs should show you the timing of the pages that are being delivered swapped.  I think the most clues will come from pursuing the swapped page scenario.

Comment: That was of course my first thought, but I've been over my code many times and failed to find anything. Like I said, it isn't just a few objects that are being swapped, it's the entire request context, cookies and all.

Comment: Marcus did you manage to find anything? I am also facing the same issue but only once as reported by client with print screens. I am using JDK6, Tomcat 6, Struts 1.0 and tiles. I am unable to replicate or see any issue in the code. I followed the log trace done by our code and it really looks like tomcat have muddled the session and shown the page requested by other user at the same time. There is no Apache web server involved in between.

Comment: I've posted an answer with the solution we found: use HTTP proxying instead of AJP. If you're getting the issue without any proxying involved at all, then I've no idea how to help. Sorry.

Comment: Could you provide some more information about your configuration?  Versions of Apache, Tomcat, JVM (and which JVM, since Gentoo provides some options there)?  How much load are we talking about (in sessions/min or connections/min)?

Comment: Gentoo Base System release 1.12.11.1; Tomcat 6, Apache 2.2; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.3-b02, mixed mode). The load is not particularly high by the scale of such things.

Comment: I experienced the same thing with mod_proxy_ajp, and have reported it upstream with a test case here: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=53727. By the way, did you encounter intermittent 502 error after switching to mod_proxy_http?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We switched Apache from proxying with AJP to proxying with HTTP. So far it appears to have solved the issue, or at least vastly reduced it - the problem hasn't been reported in months, and the app's use has increased since then.

The change is in Apache's httpd.conf. Having started with `mod_jk`:

```
JkMount /portal ajp13
```

We switched to `mod_proxy_ajp`:

```
ProxyPass /portal ajp://localhost:8009/portal
```

Then finally to straight `mod_proxy`:

```
ProxyPass /portal http://localhost:8080/portal
```

You'll need to make sure Tomcat is set up to serve HTTP on port 8080. And remember that if you're serving `/`, you need to include `/` on both sides of the proxy or it starts crying:

```
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
```

Answer (score 6):

Could it be the thread-safety of your servlets?

Do your servlets store any information in instance members.

For example, something as simple as the following may cause thread-related issues:

```
public class MyServlet ... {
    private String action;

    public void doGet(...) {
         action = request.getParameter("action");
         processAction(response);
    }

    public void processAction(...) {
         if (action.equals("foo")) {
             // send foo page
         } else if (action.equals("bar")) {
             // send bar page
         }
     }
}
```

Because the serlvet is accessed by multiple threads, there is no guarantee that the action instance member will not be clobbered by someone elses request, and end up sending the wrong page back.

The simple solution to this issue is to use local variables insead of instance members:

```
public class MyServlet ... {
    public void doGet(...) {
         String action = request.getParameter("action");
         processAction(action, response);
    }

    public void processAction(...) {
         if (action.equals("foo")) {
             // send foo page
         } else if (action.equals("bar")) {
             // send bar page
         }
     }
}
```

**Note: this extends to JavaServer Pages too, if you were dispatching to them for your views?**

Comment: Good thought, but no, I don't believe it is. I don't keep any shared state (except for a very few cached database objects that I'm careful to make thread-safe)

Comment: I'm upvoting you, because while it didn't solve my problem, it's not a bad place to start for somebody else who lands here.

Answer (score 3):

Check if your headers allow caching without the correct `Vary` HTTP header (if you use session cookies, for instance, and allow caching, you need an entry in the `Vary` HTTP header for the cookie header, or a cache/proxy might serve the cached version of a page intended for one user to another user).

The problem might be not with caching on your web server, but on another layer of caching (either on a reverse proxy in front of your web server, or on a proxy near the users). If the clients are behing a NAT, they might also be behind a transparent proxy (and, to make things even harder to debug, the transparent proxy might be configured to not be visible in the headers).

Comment: Is there any way I can find out where and how my pages are being cached?

Comment: Unless whatever does the caching adds the extra HTTP headers (mostly Via and X-Forwarded-For), or you control the client and can try a tcptraceroute ou HTTP TRACE, you can't.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/262742/iis-6net-2how-can-user-a-get-the-user-cookie-for-unrelated-user-b-who-is-in-a-d#262786

Comment: Since I followed this advice the problem has apparently cleared up. I still don't know the cause, but I'm going to mark this as the answer anyway.

Comment: Sorry for un-accepting your answer, but the problem has come back.

Answer (score 2):

8 updates of the question later one more issue to use to test/reproduce, albeit it might be difficult (or expensive) for public sites.

You could enable https on the sites. This would at least wipe out any other proxies caches along the way. It'd be bad to see that there are some forgotten loadbalancers or company caches on the way that interfere with your traffic.

For public sites this would imply trusted certificates on the keys, so some money will be involved. For testing self-signed keys might suffice. Also, check that there's no transparent proxy involved that decrypts and reencrypts the traffic. (they are easily detectable, as they can't use the same certificate/key as the original server)

Comment: Interesting. I can probably enable HTTPS on at least the logged-in parts of the site, and if/when the issue happens again I'll test if the HTTPS-delivered parts are affected. That might help, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Although you did mention mod_cache was not enabled in your setup, for others who may have encountered the same issue with mod_cache enabled (even on static contents), the solution is to make sure the following directive is enabled on the Set-Cookie HTTP header:

```
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
```

The reason being mod_cache will cache the Set-Cookie header that may get served to other users. This would then leak session ID from the user who last filled the cache to another.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it really drove me nuts. I dont know why, but I solved it turning off the Keep Alive on the http.conf

from

KeepAlive             On

to

KeepAlive             Off

My application doesn't use the keepalive feature, so it worked very well for me.

Comment: Despite seemingly positive results, I've now established that KeepAlive can't be the problem. :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.1
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); //HTTP 1.0
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); //prevents caching at the proxy server
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this site, it describes an issue with mod_jk.  I came accross your posting while looking at a very similar issue.  Basically the fix is to upgrade to a newer version of mod_jk.  I haven't had a chance to implement the change in our server yet, but I'm going to try this tomorrow and see if it helps.

http://securitytracker.com/alerts/2009/Apr/1022001.html

Comment: Thanks! But why are we getting the same problem with mod_proxy_ajp instead of mod_jk?

Comment: Not sure, but we're having this issue as well.  We tried the suggestion in that article and upgraded to the latest version of isapi driver and we're still having issues.  Have you found a solution or did you switch to Glassfish?

Comment: We've switched to using a straight proxy rather than AJP, as discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/956361/apache-tomcat-using-modproxy-instead-of-ajp

Comment: So far the problem hasn't reappeared, but that doesn't prove it's fixed. And using a straight proxy does have a slight performance cost.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert, but could it be some weird [Network Address Translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) issue?

Comment: Interesting idea. The server isn't behind NAT (all our servers have global IPs), but of course the clients are. I wonder if Apache does anything special to accomodate that?

Answer (score 0):

It may be not a caching issue at all. Try to increase MaxClients parameter in apache2.conf. If it is too low (150 by default?), Apache starts to queue requests. When it decides to serve queued request via mod_proxy it pulls out a wrong page (or may be it is just stressed doing all the queuing).

Comment: I agree it probably isn't caching, but evidence suggests that the proxy method used makes a difference. And the problem was visible with just a couple of users, so I don't see how they could rake up 150 concurrent requests. Still, this is good advice generally.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that is the page that somebody else requested or a page without parameters?,
you could get weird errors if your connectionTimeout is too short at server.xml on the tomcat server behind apache, increase it to a bigger number:

default configuration:

```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="20000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

changed:

```
  <Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
               connectionTimeout="2000000"
               redirectPort="8443" />
```

Comment: It was definitely returning somebody else's data, based on lines like "You are logged in as John". But it's gone two years now since the question was relevant.