# IIS 6/.Net 2:How can user A get the user cookie for unrelated user B who is in a different session and on another box?

Tags: .net, asp.net, .net-2.0, iis-6

1) user A goes to the site, creates an account, and logs in
2) user b goes to the site.  Rather than having to log in, user b enters as though user b is user a.  User b gets access to all of user a's data and can brows the site as user a.

Note: user b does not log in.  User b just hits the site, and the site returns as if user b is already logged in as user a.

Note 2: user a and user b are on distinct computers.  Also, static variables are not involved in the code.

Setup:
IIS 6
.Net 2.0
OutputCache off for the pages in the site

Comment: can you include more information?  When you say "user b enters as though user b is user a" do you mean that user b knows user a username and password?

Comment: are you asking how to make this happen or for an explanation of something you are seeing happen?

Comment: Are users A and B on the same computer?

Comment: Trying to explain how something we're seeing could happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question seems quite similar to [Apache/Tomcat error - wrong pages being delivered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246540/apachetomcat-error-wrong-pages-being-delivered). As [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246540/apachetomcat-error-wrong-pages-being-delivered#248724) to that question mentions, if you use session cookies, check if your `Vary` header is correct.

Comment: How do you translate this to IIS settings?

Comment: Accepting answer as the issue appears to be a known caching issue.  See answer 4 for info on the known ms issue.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are not storing any data in static (c#) or Shared (VB) variables.

Answer (score 0):

From research by other team members:

> Even though the authentication cookie may be in images from the portal, an
>   authentication cookie with a ticket for David should never have been sent to
>   Todd's browser.  Also if images are cached somwhere somehow such that different
>   users get other user's auth cookies then I assume this problem would happen
>   fairly often and should be repeatable.  However I am wondering if this is a
>   load balanced system and if so does the load balancer cache anything?

Based on the known issue of users sharing sessions as a result of output
caching with ASP.NET, IIS 6.0, and Windows 2003 Server, the problem may only be
repeatable 1 out of 100,000 requests (see the 'Sessions and Output Caching'
section of this article) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163577.aspx