# Using ProxyPass for pages but not images

Tags: apache, proxy, mod-jk, ajp, proxypass

As a result of [horrible, horrible errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246540/apache-tomcat-error-wrong-pages-being-delivered), we've changed how we connect Apache to Tomcat. We were using `mod_jk`:

```
JkMount /path ajp13
```

Now we're using `mod_proxy_ajp`:

```
ProxyPass /path ajp://localhost:8009/path
ProxyPassReverse /path ajp://localhost:8009/path
```

However, there's a feature that `JkMount` offered but `ProxyPass` doesn't: the ability to select on file types. This made it possible to proxy html files, but not images - in other words, to let the nice fast Apache serve the static stuff, and resorting to the slow Tomcat only for the dynamic stuff.

```
JkMount /*.html ajp13
```

Is there any way of achieving this with `ProxyPass`? Possibly using a surrounding `<Location>` directive or something like that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [ProxyPassMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch):

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/(path/.*\.html)$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1
```

<sub>Edited: Marcus Downing’s correction</sub>

Comment: Are there performance implications of using a regular expression?

Comment: Regular expression have some performance issues when you have overcomplex expressions.  For this kind of regular expression it’s ok.

Answer (score 2):

Not your issue but something to watch out for using this configuration.  While using apache mod_proxy to connect to tomcat my error log was showing dropped connections under moderate load.
Adding this to httpd.conf solved my problems.

```
SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1
SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
```

Comment: Can you explain what these do?

Comment: turns off keep alive connections and makes the request use http 1.0 instead of 1.1

Comment: Correct.  I believe the original errors messages where a symptom of a different problem but I was receiving them on both internal and 3rd party apps on the same tomcat instance.  Anyhow this these changes cleared up the error log.

Answer (score 1):

kmkaplan's post is the right answer, but it gave me the error:

```
Syntax error on line 32 of .../httpd-vhosts.conf:
ProxyPass Unable to parse URL
```

It worked when I changed the directive to read:

```
ProxyPathMatch ^/(path/.*\.html)$ ajp://localhost:8009/$1
```

I can only assume that putting the `$1` right next to the port number `8009` was confusing it.

Answer (score 0):

We use the following to let Apache serve images and set reasonable expires headers:

```
<Virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com

    Alias /img/ /var/www/domain/img/
    <Directory /var/www/domain/img/>
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 months"
        ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 months"
        ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 months"
        ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 months"
        ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 months"
        ExpiresByType image/ico "access plus 1 months"
        # This will prevent apache from having to check for a .htaccess file on each request.
        AllowOverride None
        # Allow symlinks. Otherwise, apache will make a separate call on each filename to ensure it is not a symlink.
        Options +FollowSymLinks -SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ProxyRequests Off
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    # Prevent domain.com/img from being served by Tomcat
    ProxyPass /img !

    # Pass all other requests to Tomcat
    ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/

    # 1. Note that usually no ProxyPassReverse directive is necessary. The AJP request includes
    #    the original host header given to the proxy, and the application server can be expected to
    #    generate self-referential headers relative to this host, so no rewriting is necessary. 
    # 2. If you still want to use it, read this first:
    #    http://www.humboldt.co.uk/2009/02/the-mystery-of-proxypassreverse.html
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://domain.com/
</Virtualhost>
```

However, as you can see, we store images outside of our Tomcat application. I don't know if it also works for images inside the application.