# Apache + Tomcat: Using mod_proxy instead of AJP

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-proxy, ajp

Is there any way I connect Apache to Tomcat using an HTTP proxy such that Tomcat gets the correct incoming host name rather than localhost? I'm using this directive in apache:

```
ProxyPass /path http://localhost:8080/path
```

But it comes through as localhost, which is useless when we have a bunch of sites on the same server. I could set the host manually in the server config:

```
<Connector port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           proxyName="pretend.host" proxyPort="80" />
```

But that again doesn't serve more than one site. And I don't like the idea of using a different internal port for each site, that sounds really ugly.

Is there no way to transfer the port when I proxy it?

(If you ask why I don't just use AJP, the answer is [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/246540/apache-tomcat-error-wrong-pages-being-delivered). I'm trying everything I can before giving up on [Tomcat and Apache entirely](https://serverfault.com/questions/589/alternatives-to-apache))

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The settings you are looking for are:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName public.server.name

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that we're using localhost as the proxy target. We can do this since we enable [ProxyPreserveHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost). The documentation states that

> It is mostly useful in special configurations like proxied mass name-based virtual hosting, where the original Host header needs to be evaluated by the backend server.

which sounds exactly like what you are doing.

Comment: How would you cater for static files? I.e. how would you tell Apache to server everything requested from `/static` how would you set the document root for this?

Comment: @Luke - ProxyPassMatch should help you : http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch

Answer (score 5):

I think your best bet if you want multiple sites on the same server is to use virtual hosts in your Apache configuration.  Here's an example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName server.domain.com

ProxyRequests Off
<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://server.domain.com:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://server.domain.com:8080/
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

As long as you have server.domain.com registered in your external DNS, the incoming host name will be displayed in client URLs.  I'm running a single server hosting 6 separate sites, including 3 that are back by Tomcat, using this method.

Comment: We are of course using virtual hosts in Apache, but I was using localhost in the ProxyPass directive. Using the appropriate domain instead is acceptable, but not quite perfect - it overrides the domain on which the request came in, information which is then used down the line.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use AJP, and you should since it's faster than HTTP. Just make sure to enable it in http.conf:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
```

In that case, this configuration works for me:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName public.server.name

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>

  ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8080/
# ProxyPassReverse might not be needed,
# it's only for redirecting from inside.
#  ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```