# Apache subdomain redirect into Tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, subdomain, mod-proxy, mod-jk

I'm pretty new to Apache HTTP, and sysadmin-ing in general, so i have this question
I have a domain (www.doamin.com) with an Apache listening to port 80,
also I have an Apache Tomcat on the same domain configured to port 8080.

Is there a way to configure a subdomain (i.e, tomcat.domain.com)
so it will redirect into my tomcat specific application,
so user can access applications through app1.domain.com and app2.domain.com (and it will be served by Tomcat)?

I've seen a lot of mentioning to

> mod_jk

and

> mod_proxy

but all of the post assumed prior knowledge with Apache.
can someone walk me thorugh?

Many thanks, -PK.

Answer (score 10):

mod_jk is outdated. It is recomended to use mod_proxy (mod_proxy_http or mod_proxy_ajp) to connect forward requests to your apache server to the tomcat.

1. define a virtual host in your apache config
2. create a proxy directive that forwards your requests to tomcat

Maybe this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/956361/apache-tomcat-using-mod-proxy-instead-of-ajp) give you some hints.

You can define two virtual hosts (app1.domain.tld and app2.domain.tld) that have proxy definitions for their designated apps. Example for app1:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName app1.domain.tld
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/app1
    ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/app1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: even though this wasn't the exact answer it helped me to get closer to what I needed, thanks!

Comment: You really expected an *exact* tutorial that shows how to configure Apache HTTPD and Tomcat for your purpos?

Comment: no, but I would expect hints on creating 2 VH.
don't get me wrong dude, you've been a HUGE help!!

Answer (score 5):

while Magomi was almost right,

Presenting an exact way to do it.

1. Add your subdomain to the DNS server
2. integrate *mod_proxy* into *httpf.conf* :

> ```
> LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
> LoadModule proxy_ajp_module modules/mod_proxy_ajp.so
> LoadModule proxy_balancer_module modules/mod_proxy_balancer.so
> LoadModule proxy_connect_module modules/mod_proxy_connect.so
> LoadModule proxy_ftp_module modules/mod_proxy_ftp.so
> LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
> LoadModule proxy_scgi_module modules/mod_proxy_scgi.so
> ```

1. define two virtual hosts as following

   > NameVirtualHost *:80
   >
   > ```
   > <VirtualHost *:80>
   >     ServerName application.domain.com
   >     ProxyRequests Off
   >     ProxyPreserveHost On
   >     <Proxy *>
   >         Order deny,allow
   >         Allow from all
   >     </Proxy>
   >     ProxyPass / http://www.domain.com:8080/application/
   >     ProxyPassReverse / http://www.domain.com:8080/application/
   > </VirtualHost>
   >
   > <VirtualHost *:80>
   >     DocumentRoot C:\<pathToApache>\www
   >     ServerName www.domain.com
   > </VirtualHost>
   > ```

This will direct your site (www.domain.com) to your Apache HTTP server, and redirect all calls to *Application* to the Tomcat.

Hope this Helps,

**-PK**