# How to debug Crosstalk occurring on Apache/HTTPD?

Tags: apache, tomcat, ajp

I've got my webapp running on Tomcat 7 and Java 8. It's a Grails app with Atmosphere framework. When I connect to it directly from the browser, everything is fine.

However when I proxy it using Apache/HTTPD 2.4, occasionally, I see some crosstalk. By crosstalk I mean, when multiple users are trying to access the setup over HTTPS, some users see the response to another user's request.

What would be the best way to debug such a problem? I couldn't find a similar problem on Apache's Bugzilla, but it's possible I'm using the wrong keywords.

This is the content of my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/proxy.conf`

```
ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /foo/stomp/ ws://localhost:8080/foo/stomp/
ProxyPassReverse /foo/stomp/ ws://localhost:8080/foo/stomp/

ProxyPass /foo/atmosphere-ws/ ws://localhost:8080/foo/atmosphere/
ProxyPassReverse /foo/atmosphere-ws/ ws://localhost:8080/foo/atmosphere/

ProxyPass /foo/ ajp://localhost:8009/foo/
ProxyPass /foo  ajp://localhost:8009/foo/
```

Edit: Per symcbean's comments, here are the headers

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 17 Mar 2016 18:00:58 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Atmosphere-tracking-id: 3ef14a8f-fe1b-480e-865c-40152f51ca72
Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Content-Language: en-US
Content-Length: 8799
X-Protocol: https
Connection: close
```

There is no caching on the headers.

Thanks!

Comment: I suggeest the first thing you do is publish details of the response headers for URLs exhibiting the behaviour so we know that Apache shouldn't cache and re-use the content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246540/apache-tomcat-error-wrong-pages-being-delivered?rq=1 seems similar. I'm going to attempt that and update this if complaints go away.